# Problems by inserting multiple files into database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to database designing and I'm working on an upload formula.

In my example I have 3 input buttons. The upload of all selected file to my uploads folder works fine, but my problem is, only the first of all  selected files gets inserted in my database.

**Here is my code:**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
if (isset($_POST['upload_docs'])) {

   for($mi = 0; $mi < count($_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name']); $mi++) {

     $doc = $_FILES['sel_doc']['name'][$mi];
     $tmp_doc = $_FILES['sel_doc']['tmp_name'][$mi];
     $target = "doc_uploads/". basename($doc);

     if (move_uploaded_file($$tmp_doc, $target)) {
       echo "Upload successfully!";
     }
     else {
       echo "Upload failed!";
     }
   }
}
```

```
$sql_f = "INSERT INTO docs (doc_file) VALUES ('$doc')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql_f);
```

```
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div>
   <input type="file" name="sel_doc[]" multiple="multiple">
   <input type="file" name="sel_doc[]" multiple="multiple">
   <input type="file" name="sel_doc[]" multiple="multiple">
</div>

<div id="sel_button">
<button type="submit" name="upload_docs">upload</button>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Your insert is outside the loop. If you want one insert per doc, you need to move it inside the loop.

Comment: `multiple="multiple"` will cause issues as your php does not handle array of arrays.

Comment: oh yes, you are right, it isn't in the loop, this was the problem ... Thank you

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm too newbie to understand what do you talking about ... For now i want that my website works as I imagine it should do. The security stuff i will add at the end, when I'm more experienced.